# Struggling with the output of directory information

Tags: python, for-loop, import, active-directory

I'm working on changing directories and pulling information like file size to complete the output.  This is what I have.  I am looking to get my output to seperate the catnames.txt and cats.jpg as well as the dognames.txt and dogs.jpg.  And adding the bytes afterward.

```
   import os
   totalSize = 0
   Path.cwd()
   print(Path.cwd())
   os.chdir('C:\cpt180Stuff')
   print(Path.cwd())
   print("The CPT180Stuff folder contains the following: " + 
   str(os.listdir('C:\\cpt180stuff')))
   print("The CPT180Stuff\cars folder contains the following: " + 
   str(os.listdir('C:\\cpt180stuff\\cars')))
   print("The CPT180Stuff\pets folder contains the following: " + 
   str(os.listdir('C:\\cpt180stuff\\pets')))
   os.chdir('C:\\cpt180stuff\pets\cats')
   for filename in os.listdir('C:\\cpt180stuff\\pets\\cats'):
    totalSize = totalSize + 
    os.path.getsize(os.path.join("C:\\cpt180stuff\pets\cats", filename))
    print("The CPT180Stuff\pets\cats folder contains the following: " ) 
    print("catnames.txt: " + str((totalSize)))
   for filename in os.listdir('C:\\cpt180stuff\\pets\\dogs'):
    totalSize = totalSize + 
    os.path.getsize(os.path.join("C:\\cpt180stuff\pets\dogs", filename))
    print("The CPT180Stuff\pets\dogs folder contains the following: " ) 
    print("dognames.txt: " + str((totalSize)))


This is my output  
C:\Users\Brandan\Desktop\CLASSES\CPT180 Shell Scripting\Chapter 9
C:\cpt180Stuff
The CPT180Stuff folder contains the following: ['cars', 'cpt180.txt', 'pets']
The CPT180Stuff\cars folder contains the following: ['familycars', 'sportscars']
The CPT180Stuff\pets folder contains the following: ['cats', 'dogs']
The CPT180Stuff\pets\cats folder contains the following: 
catnames.txt: 34
The CPT180Stuff\pets\cats folder contains the following: 
catnames.txt: 39173
The CPT180Stuff\pets\dogs folder contains the following: 
dognames.txt: 39207
The CPT180Stuff\pets\dogs folder contains the following: 
dognames.txt: 98727

This is what it should be
[enter image description here][1]

 How can I fix this?  I really need to understand this.


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3Ade.png
```

Comment: dont use images to show us code, just paste the code into the question in order to help you

Comment: Sorry new to this.